# Presentations With Mathematica on the Silver Screen?

Tags: notebooks, slideshows

My book is complete. I have copies of my book in the word document and pdf document formats. I have the 27 Mathematica notebooks I built to write the book. How do I present this material to a live audience? What sort of software / hardware combinations do I need to project my book one page at a time on the silver screen? How do I scroll through a Mathematica notebook on the silver screen?